# Dichotomy of Riemannian holonomy groups

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Berger's list of irreducible Riemannian holonomies contains two sorts of holonomy groups. The first ($SO(n)$, $U(m)$ and $Sp(k)\cdot Sp(1)$) consists of holonomy groups of rank one symmetric spaces (only $\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ is missing). These symmetric spaces are witnesses of the fact that these holonomy groups have examples that are not Ricci-flat.

The other holonomies ($SU(m)$, $Sp(k)$, $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ and $G_2$) all admit parallel spinors (either locally or assuming that the underlying manifolds are simply connected) and are therefore Ricci flat by a theorem of Hitchin and Friedrich.

Is there a conceptual explanation for this dichotomy (better than: "just look at Berger's list")? For example, can one prove directly that an irreducible Riemannian manifold that does not admit (local) parallel spinors must have the holonomy group of a symmetric space?

Comment: It was proven (I think by Alekseevsky), that simply connected complete Riemannian manifolds with holonomy $Spin_9$ are isometric either to $F_4/Spin_9$ or to $F_4^{-20}/Spin 9.$ So that group should be in the list but on the other hand doesn't allow any non-symmetric examples.

Comment: Berger's original list *did* include $\mathrm{Spin}(9)\subset\mathrm{SO}(16)$ among the possible non-symmetric holonomies, but Alexseevsky later showed that a Riemannian manifold $(M^{16},g)$ (not necessarily complete) whose holonomy is isomorphic to $\mathrm{Spin}(9)\subset\mathrm{SO}(16)$ is, up to constant scaling, locally isometric to either the symmetric space $\mathbb{OP}^2 = \mathrm{F}_4/\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ or its non-compact dual, so it was removed from the list.   (Note that, because these metrics are not Ricci-flat, they do not admit any parallel spinor fields.)

Comment: You are both right, of course. I should have added the words "of not locally symmetric manifolds" at some point in the first sentence and say that I refer to the revised version of Berger's list.